Find the trace of matrix be its minimal polynomial
I found this problem in last year materials of my linear algebra course. And I am really interested in solving it
There is a Matrix
$$\begin{matrix}
3 & * & * & * & * & 9 \\
 * & * & * & * & * & * \\
 * & * & * & * & * & * \\
 * & * & * & * & * & * \\
 * & * & * & * & * & * \\
 3 & * & * & * & * & 3
\end{matrix}$$
Under * are some real values(not necessary equal)
Also given minimal polynomial of this matrix. $f=x^5-2$
Is it possible by this data to determine a trace of matrix?
I know that trace of matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues and so the trace is equal to 0, but I think this fact is not what should be used here cause we don’t have enough knowledge yet to prove it.
Is there any other way to prove the trace is 0?

The minimal polynomial has $5$ different roots whose sum is equal $0.$ Since the matrix is of dimension $6\times 6,$ one of the roots of $x^5-2$ is a double root of the characteristic polynomial. As the trace is a real number $2^{1/5}$ is the double root. Hence the trace is equal $2^{1/5}.$
